# Migrating from Monolithic to GCP serverless

Tags: terraform

We are a small team implementing a migration from a traditional monolithic VM based architecture with on-prem datacentres to GCP serverless and/or microservice architecture.

We are starting with some small applications and lifting and shifting with some POC's. Is it worth automating the VM setup with packer and terraform for the orchestration for one of our POC's, or focus on the IaC setup mainly and keep the VM's to be set up manually - as they are now - and possibly would rarely need to be reinstalled (maybe).

Also, what are some possible CICD tools and patterns that we should choose?

We currently use Bamboo for scripting our build and deployment but have limited testing baked in and have not yet evolved to IaC.

Many thanks for your time and patience.